# Можно ли с помощью PHP вызвать Javascript код?

Tags: php, javascript, запрос

Сервис WalletOne после успешной оплаты делает POST запрос к указанному url и отправляет данные об оплате. Мне нужно, чтобы после оплаты я смог вызвать Javascript код (для добавления инфы в электронную коммерцию Яндекс Метрики), но при PHP запросе Javascript не работает.

Можно ли как-нибудь с PHP отправить запрос к JS и ждать ответа?

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код для яндекс метрики вероятнее всего должен исполняться на клиенте (в браузере пользователя). А PHP исполняется на сервере. Вы можете в браузер пользователя в качестве ответа выплюнуть js-скрипт, который исполнится браузером, если действие не требует сто процентной надежности. Если нужно железно отправить запрос в метрику прям во время оплаты на сервере - в конце концов js-код метрики посылает некоторый запрос на сервер Яндекса. Можно раскопать API и попытаться выполнить тот же самый запрос CURL'ом.

P.S. Отвечая прямо на ваш вопрос: можно вызвать из PHP-кода JS-код и дождаться пока он исполнится. Для этого нужен серверный компилятор для JS - Node, но код яндекс.метрики написан не под него и скорее всего он не заработает. И вообще вам это не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Попытался через API попробовать, там можно добавлять счетчики, цели и т.д., но товары кажется нельзя.